# How manage multiple DB with MongoLab and Heroku?

Tags: heroku, mlab

I have a project hosted on Heroku using Mongolab for storing data (MongoDB).
I need to create 2 different DB instances: one for prod, one for dev.

Any idea how can I do and how I can tell my code which one to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a config variable (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to set the database url and then use the environment variable in your mongo initializer. Set one app to use the production url and a dev app to use the developer database url.

Comment: OK for the configuration environnement,
But how can i generate a new DB URI from heroku ?
Thanks,

Comment: i have already read it, but they doesn't say how to install 2 URI on the same project.
On irc , people says to me it is impossible.
(sorry for my bad english..)

Comment: you can't install duplicate addons of the same you would have two seperate apps on heroku with their own databases.